# Ubuntu 18 LTS , Stuck on "Updates and other software" during installation

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I am using Asus A541uj with Nvidia 920mx.
I got stuck *(as seen in the image below)* every time on "Updates and other software" during installation.

[image]

I created a bootable USB with Rufus & Universal USB Installer.
Tried both GPT/MBR, DD/ISO, BIOS/UEFI, UEFI/Non-CMS in Rufus.
Tried BIOS Settings Fastboot off/On, CMS On/Off (No other option is given in my bios) to no success.

Answer (score 0):

with Nvidia cards you need to add nomodeset to the grub boot parameter.
[here is how to do that.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks, It successfully installed but got another problem, ubuntu is creating large log file syslog & kern.log. How can i resolve this prob.